# Multiple WKInterfaceLabel on WKInterfaceTable

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

[image: Multiple WKInterfaceLabel on WKInterfaceTable]

Does anyone know how to add multiple WKInterfaceLabel on WKInterfaceTable row? I can't arrange the the WKInterfaceLabel position on storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother everyone.

This is the answer:

Inside the Storyboard, Select Group > Attribute Inspector > Layout vertical